# Camunda Task List - Automatically preview / open User Task if assigned to current user

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I would like my Camunda task list to automatically display the next task form  if next task is assigned to the current user.

At the moment this only happens on a click event , that fires the focus function, within a ng repeat of all tasks.

```
ng-click="focus($event, task)"
```